# Callback for redirected requests Scrapy

Tags: web-crawler, redirect, scrapy

I am trying to scrape using scrape framework. Some requests are redirected but the callback function set in the start_requests is not called for these redirected url requests but works fine for the non-redirected ones.

I have the following code in the start_requests function:

```
for user in users:
    yield scrapy.Request(url=userBaseUrl+str(user['userId']),cookies=cookies,headers=headers,dont_filter=True,callback=self.parse_p)
```

But this self.parse_p is called only for the Non-302 requests.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess you get a callback for the final page (after the redirect). Redirects are been taken care by the `RedirectMiddleware`. You could disable it and then you would have to do all the redirects manually. If you wanted to selectively disable redirects for a few types of Requests you can do it like this:

```
request =  scrapy.Request(url, meta={'dont_redirect': True} callback=self.manual_handle_of_redirects)
```

I'm not sure that the intermediate Requests/Responses are very interesting though. That's also what `RedirectMiddleware` believes. As a result, it does the redirects automatically and saves the intermediate URLs (the only interesting thing) in:

```
response.request.meta.get('redirect_urls')
```

You have a few options!

Example spider:

```
import scrapy

class DimSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "dim"

    start_urls = (
        'http://example.com/',
    )

    def parse(self, response):
        yield scrapy.Request(url="http://example.com/redirect302.php", dont_filter=True, callback=self.parse_p)

    def parse_p(self, response):
       print response.request.meta.get('redirect_urls')
       print "done!"
```

Example output...

```
DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.example.com/> (referer: None)
DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET http://myredirect.com> from <GET http://example.com/redirect302.php>
DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://myredirect.com/> (referer: http://example.com/redirect302.com/)
['http://example.com/redirect302.php']
done!
```

If you really want to scrape the 302 pages, you have to explicitcly allow it. For example here, I allow `302` and set `dont_redirect` to `True`:

```
handle_httpstatus_list = [302]
def parse(self, response):
    r = scrapy.Request(url="http://example.com/redirect302.php", dont_filter=True, callback=self.parse_p)
    r.meta['dont_redirect'] = True
    yield r
```

The end result is:

```
DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.example.com/> (referer: None)
DEBUG: Crawled (302) <GET http://example.com/redirect302.com/> (referer: http://www.example.com/)
None
done!
```

This spider should manually follow 302 urls:

```
import scrapy

class DimSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "dim"

    handle_httpstatus_list = [302]

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request("http://page_with_or_without_redirect.html",
                             callback=self.parse200_or_302, meta={'dont_redirect':True})

    def parse200_or_302(self, response):
        print "I'm on: %s with status %d" % (response.url, response.status)
        if 'location' in response.headers:
            print "redirecting"
            return [scrapy.Request(response.headers['Location'],
                                  callback=self.parse200_or_302, meta={'dont_redirect':True})]
```

Be careful. Don't omit setting `handle_httpstatus_list = [302]` otherwise you will get "HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed".

Comment: I have edited the question with the code and the call to the callback. The behavior you have described doesn't work for the requests that get redirected after the 302 code.

Comment: Also, I guess the better way of framing this would be. The code doesn't crawl the redirected urls.

Comment: Updated with some elements from your updated question. I will also add a case for `dont_redirect` `meta` (which might not be that interesting though)

Comment: Updated the example above.

Comment: I tried both the cases that you have mentioned above. 
1. In first case the for the 302 requests the callback function doesn't get called. 
2. It doesn't give the redirected link. It just stops at the Crawled(200) 
Do I need to set some parameters in the settings.py ?

Comment: Your target URL after capturing 302 (case 2) will be in `response.headers['Location']`

Comment: "It just stops at the Crawled(200)" ... I don't understand - what 200? Let's focus on the cases you get 302. You can distinguish between the 200 responses and the 302 ones by checking `response.status`. "Do I need to set some parameters in the settings.py ?" I wouldn't expect to.

Comment: Updated answer with one last spider which should clarify everything :)

Comment: I basically replicated your code. I have noticed the following behavior, it creates a GET request for the 302 code with the new url in the location, however it doesn't make the call to the callback function. I was able to verify this by printing the response inside the callback function. It would print for the first request but nothing was printed for the callback request.

Comment: I tried with lesser number of links. It actually schedules these callbacks for later in queue.

Answer (score 0):

By default, scrapy is not following 302 redirects.

In your spider you can make use of the [custom_settings](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html?highlight=custom_settings#scrapy.spiders.Spider.custom_settings) attribute:

> custom_settings
>   A dictionary of settings that will be overridden from the project wide configuration when running this spider. It must be defined as a class attribute since the settings are updated before instantiation.

Set the number of redirects that a url request can be redirected as follows:

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
  name = "myspider"
  allowed_domains = ["example.com"]
  start_urls = [ "http://www.example.com" ]

  custom_settings = { 'REDIRECT_MAX_TIMES': 333 }

  def start_requests(self):
      # Your code here
```

I set 333 as an example limit.

I hope this helps.