# How to get the urls those are with error status

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I am writing a spider with scrapy in python3, and l just started scrapy not a long time. I was catching the data of a web-site and after some minutes, web site maybe get me the `302` status and redirect to another url to verify me. So l want to save the url to the file.

for example, `https://www.test.com/article?id=123` is what I want to request, and then it response me `302` an redirect to `https://www.test.com/vrcode`

I want to save `https://www.test.com/article?id=123` to file, how should I do?

```
class CatchData(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'test'

    allowed_domains = ['test.com']

    start_urls = ['test.com/article?id=1',
                  'test.com/article?id=2',
                  # ...
                 ]

    def parse(self, response):
        item = LocationItem()
        item['article'] = response.xpath('...')
        yield item
```

I found a answer from [How to get the scrapy failure URLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13724730/how-to-get-the-scrapy-failure-urls)

but It is an answer at six years ago, I want to know is there more simple way to do this

Comment: Is https://www.test.com/vrcode an error page in the HTTP sense? What’s the HTTP status code of that response?

Comment: @Gallaecio status code is `302`

Comment: A 302 response always redirects to another response. I’m asking about the status code of the final response, the target of the redirect, not the redirect itself. If you locate https://www.test.com/vrcode in the logs, you should be able to see the corresponding status code. I ask because I suspect it may be 200, which means that the linked answer would not work for you. In any case, it conditions what you need to do.

Comment: log info from terminal seem like this `DEBUG: Crawled (302) <GET https://www.test.com/article?id=123> (referer: None)`, only this one

Comment: What does the 2 lines about `https://www.test.com/vrcode` look like?

Comment: also `DEBUG: Crawled (302) <GET https://www.test.com/vrcode> (referer: None)`

Comment: the terminal has been closed, so l cannot take a screenshot about it, But it sometimes `(302) <GET https://www.test.com/article?id=123>` and sometimes `(302) <GET https://www.test.com/vrcode>`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/35817478/939364

Answer (score 0):

```py
with open(file_name, 'w', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    f.write(str(item))
```